# difference in using Intern method in Java

Tags: java

This question might be simple just to make sure 100% sure am asking it.. What is the difference between these 2 cases
Case 1:

```
String s = "Hello";
String s2 = new String("Hello");
s2.intern();
System.out.println(s == s2);
```

Case 2:

```
String s = "Hello";
String s1 = new String("Hello").intern();
System.out.println(s == s1);
```

Now case 1 prints false and case 2 prints true.

Can some one explain why?

Comment: Read the Javadoc of intern : `When the intern method is invoked, if the pool already contains a string equal to this String object as determined by the equals(Object) method, then the string from the pool is returned. Otherwise, this String object is added to the pool and a reference to this String object is returned.`

Comment: Thanks Eran.. the difference between string pool and heap i understood but i didn't see properly ignoring the return type of intern() which is mentioned by Kayaman

Answer (score 3):

In the first example you're ignoring the return value of `s2.intern()` which returns the reference to the String in the pool (i.e. `s`).

So `s2` still references the original, non-pooled String.

Answer (score 2):

`String` are immutable so in the first example as you write :

```
String s2 = new String("Hello");
s2.intern();
```

`s2` will not change. So here :

```
System.out.println(s == s2);
```

you compare still `new String("Hello")` to `"Hello"` that don't refer the same object as one of both String was created with the `new` operator.

---

In the second example, you assign the pooled value (with `intern()`) to a `variable`:

```
String s = "Hello";
String s1 = new String("Hello").intern();
```

So here :

```
System.out.println(s == s1);
```

`s` and `s1` refer to the same object.